# How can I get a stream of a refreshing ip webcam?

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, http-streaming, webcam-capture

On many webcam sites there are jpg webcams which refresh every second instead of a uninterrupted m3u8 stream. How can I get live images every second without refreshing the Page? Or what parameters can I add to the IP adress to show a mjpg stream? On the original site there was a number in the webcam src that is changing every second. I want to have a stream of that webcam, like http://95.76.86.188:8090/?action=stream. But that is not working on every site, for example http://92.86.135.9:8080/cgi-bin/viewer/video.jpg?r=0. I want a stream that I can add in vlc, like a mjpg video.

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I want a stream with another codec than JPG. When I open a JPG, it is only one frame and needs to be refreshed every second